# How to remove background grids in gnuplot. ?? I want plain bg and getting dotted rectangular grids

Tags: background, grid, gnuplot, spectrum, dotted-line

I have already plotted eigenvalue spectrum but want to see it on plain white back ground . Someone please help to remove thode grid lines

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For gnuplot question it will always be helpful to show your minimal script and your graph result. "I want plain bg and getting dotted rectangular grids" ....??? What do you mean? Do you now want a grid or not? Have you checked the gnuplot manual? In gnuplot console type `help grid`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use this command:

```
unset grid
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node188.html).